# How to Configure custom synapsis handler for a specific API in wso2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: apache-synapse, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need to map my custom synapse handler **to a specific API** in WSO2 EI 6.1.1.
I tried below two separate methods to configure the Custom synapse Handler to map with API

**method 1:** configure the handler in EI_HOME/conf/synapse-handlers.xml
This way the handler applied to all APIs.
ref:https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Writing+a+Synapse+Handler

**method 2:** configure the handler in API xml

```
......</resource>
    <handlers>
       <handler class="org.test.TestHandler1"/>
    </handlers>
 </api>
```

this way it leads to an error when starting the  EI server.
looks like method 2 is possible on WSO2 ESB not WSO2 EI

looking for a way to do this.
*note: I am extending AbstractSynapseHandler to create custom synapse handler*

thanks in advance

Comment: The phrase "leads to an error" does not make sense. You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that you have provided contains a sample which extends *org.apache.synapse.AbstractSynapseHandler*. But if you want an API level handler, your handler should implement *org.apache.synapse.rest.Handler* instead of extending *org.apache.synapse.AbstractSynapseHandler*.
Below is a sample Handler which should work in your case.

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.rest.Handler;

public class ReqResponseHandler implements Handler {

    @Override
    public void addProperty(String s, Object o) {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<?, ?> getProperties() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext synapsisCtx) {
        System.out.println("**********Handling Request*********");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext synapsisCtx) {
        System.out.println("**********Handling Response*********");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The way that you configured the Handler in your API xml is correct. (However, note that you cannot add a handler to API through web interface.)

For more details visit WSO2 documentation through below link.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Securing+APIs